# Ruby JSON API and post request with Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I'm using postman to make post request to my rails/grape API

Here is the json object

```
{  
 "customer":{  
    "first_name":"Joe",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "phone":"999-999-9999",
    "addresses_attributes":[{  
       "address":{  
          "address1":"123 somewhere st",
          "customer_id":"",
          "address2":"",
          "city":"Moldor",
          "state":"CA",
          "zip":"99999",
          "region_id":"1"
       }
    }]
 }
}
```

If send this to a api/v1/customers.json
I get the following error message

```
"error": "first_name is missing, last_name is missing, email is missing, phone is missing",
```

If I change the JSON format to:

```
{   
    "first_name":"Joe",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "phone":"999-999-9999",
    "addresses_attributes":[{  
       "address":{  
          "address1":"123 somewhere st",
          "customer_id":"",
          "address2":"",
          "city":"Moldor",
          "state":"CA",
          "zip":"99999",
          "region_id":"1"
       }
    }]
}
```

I does creates the customer but it does not creates the address

In my Models I have

```
#customer.br
has_many :addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true

#address.rb
belongs_to :customer
```

Here is the api/vi/curtomer.rb

```
desc "Create a Customer"
params do
  requires :first_name, type: String, desc: "First Name"
  requires :last_name, type: String, desc: "Last Name"
  requires :email, type: String, desc: "Email"
  requires :phone, type: String, desc: "Phone"
  optional :notes, type: String, desc: "Notes"
end
post do


  # Tried with new instead of create

  # test = Customer.new({
  #                    first_name: params[:first_name],
  #                    last_name: params[:last_name],
  #                    email: params[:email],
  #                    phone: params[:phone],
  #                    notes: params[:notes],
  #                    addresses_attributes: params[:addresses]
  #                })


  Customer.create({
                     first_name: params[:first_name],
                     last_name: params[:last_name],
                     email: params[:email],
                     phone: params[:phone],
                     notes: params[:notes]
                     # addresses_attributes: params[:addresses]
                 })

end
```

The address looks pretty much the same as the customers
I'm not using controllers per Grapes Documentation

EDIT: to add customer.rb create code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think your json data should be:

```
{ "customer":
  {   
    "first_name":"Joe",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "phone":"999-999-9999",
    "addresses_attributes":[{    
      "address1":"123 somewhere st",
      "customer_id":"",
      "address2":"",
      "city":"Moldor",
      "state":"CA",
      "zip":"99999",
      "region_id":"1"
    }]
  }
}
```

Refer to [this example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

If it not works, show your controller code.

Comment: I'm not using controllers per Grape's documentation. I added my create code up in the original post. Thanks for the JSON format

Comment: Have changed my answer and think you can use `Customer.create(params[:customer])` to create a new customer with assocation.